# js,jquery,easyui, the param changed when passed to the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

```
function formatData_org() {
    // convert
    obj_num2.formatter = function(value, rec) {
        var baseStr='&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                + rec.s_date + '<a  class="easyui-linkbutton"     href="javascript:void(0);" plain="true" iconCls="icon-statistic" onclick=showChart_org('+"2014-05-22"+ ')></a>';
        console.log("baseStr: " + baseStr);
        return '<div id="toolbar">'+baseStr+'</div>';

};

function showChart_org(vstday){
       console.log("vstday: " + vstday);
}
```

I passed a param "2014-05-22" to showChar_org(vstday) but finally the vstday was 1987.That is a strange.The chrome console printed as follows:

```
baseStr: &nbsp;&nbsp;2014-05-22<a  class="easyui-linkbutton" href="javascript:void(0);" 
plain="true" iconCls="icon-statistic" onclick=showChart_org(2014-05-22)></a>
vstday: 1987
```

But when I change the "2014-05-22" to "2014-05-21", the result is 1988.
when I change the "2014-05-22" to "2014-05-01", the result is 2008.why?
When I add double quotes("") to the "2014-05-22" string, the result is OK. the code as folllows:

```
 var baseStr='&nbsp;&nbsp;'+ rec.s_date + '<a  class="easyui-linkbutton"href="javascript:void(0);" plain="true" iconCls="icon-statistic" onclick=showChart_org("'+"2014-05-22"+ '")></a>';
```

The chrome console printed as follows:

```
baseStr: &nbsp;&nbsp;2014-05-22<a  class="easyui-linkbutton" href="javascript:void(0);"plain="true" iconCls="icon-statistic" onclick=showChart_org("2014-05-22")></a> 
vstday: 2014-05-22
```

any help would be appreciate.

Comment: It's evaluating the argument (2014-05-22) which is 2014 minus 05 minus 22 so its sent as 1987 to the function

Comment: Thanks a lot, you give me a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `showChart_org(2014-05-20)` , its actually evaluating the date which is just number.

```
2014 - 05 = 2009

2009 - 20 = 1989
```

That's the reason why 2014-05-22 returns you 1987.

So you need to pass it as string to ignore that :)

Comment: Oh, I know.haha, thank you very much. @Rory McCrossan